# find substring from a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring

I have the following URL.

```
http://www.xyz.com/#tabname-1-12
```

I need to split 3 values from this URL:

- `tabName`: the # value but do not want -1-12)
- `1`: the first value after first "-"
- `12`: second value after second "-"

How can I do this?

Comment: `Need to split` there is a function in javascript that's called `split` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Guess what that does ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a regex and a split.

HTML:

```
<div id='url'>http://www.xyz.com/#tabname-1-12</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

    // set this to the element containing the actual URL
    var url = $('#url').html();


    // get tabname
    var tabname = url.match(/(#.+?)-/);
    tabname = tabname[1];

    // you can now use the var tabname, which contains #tabname

    var ids = url.split('-');


    var idone = ids[1];
    var idtwo = ids[2];

    // idone contains 1, idtwo contains 12.


});
```

Use `var tabname = url.match(/#(.+?)-/);` if you dont want the # in front of tabname.

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/QPxZX/

Answer (score 2):

try below regular expression

```
  #(.*)-(.*)-(.*)
```

[`DEMO`](http://rubular.com/r/RnbzR2ThKQ)

Answer (score 1):

in javascript:

```
var url = 'http://www.xyz.com/#tabname-1-12';
// get values behind last slash
var threeValues = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')).split('-'); 

var one = threeValues(0).substr(1); // get tabname
var two = threeValues(1);    
var three = threeValues(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps you. split your url with # and take 2nd part and then split with '-' and thus you would get a array like val={'tabname', '1,' '12'}. Just try it, maybe better answers waiting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to split the string twice and then you can access the values from the final array.

```
var input = "http://www.xyz.com/#tabname-1-12";
var after = input.split('#')[1]
var values = after.split('-');
document.write(values);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/E2q8q/

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is,

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var str  = "http://www.xyz.com/#tabname-1-12";
     var val1 = str.substr(20,7);
     var val2 = str.substr(28,1);
     var val3 = str.substr(31,2);

function displayVal()
{
    alert("val1 = "+val1+"\nval2 = "+val2+"\nval3 = "+val3);
}
</script>

URL: http://www.xyz.com/#tabname-1-12;

<input type="button" name="btn" value="Click" onclick="displayVal()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That will only work for this exact URL, and a tab called tabname. I doubt that is what they want.